# How to Troubleshoot .NET Website

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out what is causing a .NET 4.0 website to hang or process slowly at times.

Any given page (and its associated code) seems to run fine or function in general, and even acceptably quickly when they are just working. But, then, sporadically, any given page load will just sit and spin ... but finishes eventually. This is on a dedicated server at a local ISP. There are numerous other sites running on it (entirely classic ASP sites except this one). The other sites generally respond fine when the .NET site is hanging. The bulk of the server activity comes from an ASP forum (Snitz) on our main site. It doesn't seem to slow at all during the .NET hangs. 
Also, there's a Snitz forum in a subdirectory of the problematic site, and running in the same app pool. Mostly, I'm not seeing it having problems when the .NET pages hang. Still verifying that a bit further.

The server never seems taxed during any of this, if I watch Task Manager.

Basically, what sorts of resources might I employ to troubleshoot this? 
What pieces of the code does it sound like I need to look into or streamline?
What other places should I look for troubleshooting methods, if not here?
(And hopefully I have this in the most appropriate Stack forum.)

I'm not sure what sorts of details may in the end be necessary, but here's a smattering, short of handing out all the code for the entire site.

• Server Info: Windows Server 2003, IIS 6.0, SQL Server 2005 (9.0)

• Using C# Code-Behind; Entity Framework; LINQ to EF, as well as smatterings of LINQ to object and some SQLDataSource controls; a number of User Controls; Membership and Roles, but not Profiles, and I tie the Membership data together manually (using EF or SQL) with other user data in the same database, as well as user data for the forum; I have a DLL from ReCaptcha and from Stripe in place, though neither are used much yet.

• Calling 1 webfont and jQuery from Google's API, Google Analytics, and 1 other local JS file; as well as 1-2 local CSS files.

• 1 database for the .NET site and all its data; and 1 database for the forum; with a separate EF model for each database.

• I am using SSL on the site. I don't require it, but I do direct most everything I can towards it once someone is logged in (passively, as well as specifically when it comes to admin, profile, or transaction pages).

• I have a function in Global.asax that emails me errors when they happen. I don't get any error messages for these hangs.

• I have external monitors (Monitis) performing HTTP checks every minute for this site, our main site, and a site on a separate Apache virtual server we also rent; as well as pings to this server, the Apache server, and the local network router for our business. The HTTP checks are set to timeout at 5 sec. I almost never hear from the pings, but I get avg. 14 HTTP failures/day, but not consistently from one server or from one site - though the Apache server has largely been quiet of late, and the problematic site more problematic.

• For the last week I've used the trial of JetBrains' dotTrace, plus SQL Server Profiler's Trace tool. For SQL, I don't know so well what to look for, but the only things that stand out to me are that the main Snitz forum is the vastly greater quantity of requests; EF makes lots of logins and logouts when I test; and many of its requests are in the double-triple digit milliseconds. For what I've seen from dotTrace, the most troubling seems to have to do with logging in, but it also shows other processes as taking longer at times. Usually some recursive part of a LINQ query are the bulk of the time.

• I've run the .NET site from Visual Web Developer 2010 locally to test. It connects to the live databases, not to test databases. I haven't noticed it having problems. It, however, does not use the SSL (perhaps obviously). Need to test it further for any issues.

• I have not implemented any Stored Procedures. I'm looking at this as maybe the first thing to try.

• It doesn't seem to be spammers or bots or such slowing the site down. I've been taking steps to shut out spammers from forms for both our main site and this .NET site.

By way of actual code: relative to the login process that dotTrace points out sometimes, and as an example of places I've tied together Membership with my own data, this is from the login page, where I'm using a LoginView control. I've ignored 15 lines above it pertaining to the Page directive and to Content placeholders from the Master page, and 5 lines beneath closing things out:

```
<asp:LoginView Id="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:Login ID="UserLogin" runat="server" CssClass="FrontEndForm MembershipControl" FailureText="We were unable to log you in. Please check your username and password, and try again." onloggedin="UserLogin_LoggedIn">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <p class="FailureText"><asp:Literal ID="FailureText" Runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal></p>
                <div id="LoginUsernameContainer" class="FieldGroup clearfix">
                    <label for="UserName" class="FieldLabel">Username</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="FieldControl FieldTextBox" Text="" MaxLength="256"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="Validation FieldValidation" Text="*" ValidationGroup="LoginFields"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
                <div id="LoginPasswordContainer" class="FieldGroup clearfix">
                    <label for="Password" class="FieldLabel">Password</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="FieldControl FieldTextBox" Text="" MaxLength="128" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="Validation FieldValidation" Text="*" ValidationGroup="LoginFields"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
                <div class="FieldGroup clearfix">
                    <label for="RememberMe" class="FieldLabel">Remember me next time:</label>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" CssClass="FieldControl FieldCheckBox"></asp:CheckBox>
                </div>
                <div id="LoginButtonContainer" class="FieldGroup ButtonContainer clearfix">
                    <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" CommandName="Login" CssClass="SubmitBtn" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginFields" />
                    <a href="/password_reset.aspx" class="caption">Forgot your password?</a>
                </div>
                <div id="LoginJoinContainer" class="FieldGroup clearfix">
                    Not yet a member? <a href="/membership.aspx">Join <asp:Literal ID="JoinUsCompanyName" runat="server" Text="<%$ AppSettings:CompanyName %>"></asp:Literal> today!</a>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        You are already logged in.
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MyEntityModel;

public partial class _login : MyMain
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MyNamespace.exclude ExcludeVisitor = new MyNamespace.exclude();

            if (ExcludeVisitor.Yes)
            {
                LoginView1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void UserLogin_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MyEntities MyEntity = new MyEntities())
        {
            Login UserLogin = (Login)LoginView1.FindControl("UserLogin");
            var _NetUser = (from u in MyEntity.aspnet_Users
                                            where u.LoweredUserName == UserLogin.UserName.ToLower()
                                            select new 
                                            {
                                                UserName = u.UserName,
                                                Password = u.aspnet_Membership.Password
                                            }).SingleOrDefault();
            if (_NetUser != null)
            {
                HttpCookie SnitzCookie = new HttpCookie("Snitz01User");
                SnitzCookie["Password"] = Server.UrlEncode(_NetUser.Password.ToString());
                SnitzCookie["UserName"] = Server.UrlEncode(_NetUser.UserName.ToString());
                SnitzCookie.Path = "/";
                Response.Cookies.Add(SnitzCookie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, the above LINQ query is searching < 50 users.

UPDATE:

So far, I'm not seeing anything using Perfmon that seems radically out-of-whack, except this one little tidbit - watching ASP.NET v4.0/Request Execution Time while loading pages, I see it drag on long after the page finishes loading. I load the page, the execution time jumps up to some number, the page finishes (in my browser), but I see the line continue to sustain in Perfmon. This can then take several routes: if I sit and watch, sometimes it drops back to 0 within 10 seconds, sometimes it goes a while (like a half-minute or more) before dropping back to 0; or if I reload the page while it's still non-zeroed, the line instantly drops to 0, and the execution time starts again. More often than not any immediately subsequent reload has a short, spiked execution time and immediately drops back to 0 when the page finishes - no sustain. (Just occurring to me that I should test whether the sustain occurs on "new" page requests and never on refreshes, or whether it's mixed and independent of that.)

Anyway, what could this sustained execution time mean? and what can I do to find out what might still be executing? (I suppose starting by building a new, simple page, to see if it happens with only basic templates and such in use...)

Otherwise, I still have the suspicion that usage of .NET Membership is unreliable, and am starting to find out things I can check (like .NET's stored procedures and such) for unnecessary steps and processes. But the "sustain" issue above seems independent of .NET Membership.

UPDATE 2:
Just to tie up loose ends, it seems that the majority of the issues had to do with errors on the hard drive housing most of our websites. For whatever reason, this new .NET site showed the problems the most, but doesn't seem to outright have problems.

Many other problems seem to come from issues with our ISP getting spammed. It's hard to tell. My external monitors pinging and HTTP-requesting the sites report timeouts (after 5-7 seconds) pretty often, but the ISP rarely ever sees anything; and when they do, it either had to do with the hard drive "failing" (having errors) or some source barraging our sites.

I still have doubts as to how well my creation could handle heavy traffic; and I still have my doubts that the HDD it's housed on is solid; but for now the site is no longer continually problematic - after a disk cleanup, and some time observing the results of that.

Comment: Given your first paragraph, the most likely cause is garbage collection and/or app pool recycling.

I'd put some counters on that to see what's going on.

Comment: Connection pool size is worth examining in the perfmon counters.

Comment: OK. I'll find out how to do these things, and give them a try.

Comment: I monitored for a while, and got someone at our webhost to monitor, too. Nothing has been conclusive - maybe bottlenecks at the database, maybe aging hardware on our server. But I still have not been able to thoroughly go through and play around with the site to see if I can make problems happen or see them enough to notice a pattern.

Comment: Have you done [client side performance testing](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline) to make sure it's not an issue with the browser?

Comment: I keep trying to get to that and really test out what the browser shows, but haven't to my satisfaction. However, just today, this may be the sort of thing to answer your question. The site loads slowly; I did have the network profiler running in Firefox; it shows 3-4 sec load times for GET and POST actions on pages, and those are reflected in the .NET Request Execution Time in Perfmon. So something like that would mean not a client-side issue, correct?

Comment: Also, I've had Perfmon monitoring NumberOfActiveConnections/Pools for .NET Data Provider for SqlServer, and Worker Process Restarts/Running. I don't think they're registering correctly because they always show 0 (or 30 odd million average/maximum, in the case of Num*ActiveConnections).

Comment: I think we're finally getting to the bottom of it, and it appears to be a failing hard drive. It started having disk corruption errors this weekend, with the manifestation of that being an HTTP 500 Server error outwardly / "fatal error" 9001 internally when someone tried to log in. Once we get our sites moved over to a new updated server, we'll see if that makes both the slowness and login hangs go away.